# Set dropdown text color of SearchView with SearchManager

Tags: android, layout, searchview, android-search, android-searchmanager

My SearchView has a SearchManager as follows

```
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getCallingActivity()));
```

I want to do one simple thing: change the text color of the dropdown items. That's all. No more.

How do I do that? This implementation is part of search interface. I am using `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the hint color of search view ? if yes try to add this line inside your base theme

```
<style name="MyActionBarWidgetTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    .....
    .....
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/yourcolor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: no, the user is talking about the suggestions dropdown